# Не получается нарисовать треугольник в консольном приложении

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int g = 26;//начало печати символов в строке
int z = 2;//количество символов

for (int p = 0; p < 8; p++)//8 строк
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 52; j++)//печать в строке
    {                 
        Console.Write(" ");
        if(j == g) 
        {
            for(int s = 0; s < z; s++)
            Console.Write("*");
        }
    }             
    g = g - 1;
    z = z + 2;

}
```

Треугольник разъезжается в разные стороны
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите форму треугольника, которую вы хотите получить на консоле.

Comment: Это часом, не си шарп?

Comment: равнобедренный треугольник

Comment: @Proshka  Покажите его форму в ответе, чтобы было представление, какую форму на экране вы хотите получить.

Comment: Если переменная `p` у вас означает номер строки, то почему бы не назвать её `line`?

Comment: @VladD, например потому, что это _paragraph_

Comment: @Grundy: Тогда почему не `paragraph`?

Comment: @VladD, чтобы сократить объект текста программы :-)

Comment: @Proshka  Вы можете показать конкретную форму для заданного числа, как треугольник должен выглядеть,? Неужели это не понятно?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну тогда инджой ёр багз. (Ну то есть не ёр, а автора кода.)

Comment: Добавь картинку как это в консоли выглядит

Comment: @Proshka Да не показывайте, что у вас получилось на консоле. Покажите, как он выглядеть должен. Ну, что здесь непонятного?!

Comment: а откуда размер строки 52 символа?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы не делаете перевода строки и пишете, по сути, все в одну строку:

```
for (int p = 0; p < 8; p++)//8 строк
{
    ...

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И кстати, во внутреннем цикле пробегать все 52 колонки не нужно, достаточно `g + z`.

Comment: Большое спасибо. В который раз - невнимательность. Надо быть чуть помедленнее и вдумчивее

Comment: @Proshka не за что.